# What is the best way to draw arbitrary objects in Android?

Tags: android, view

I've recently started building my second android app and I've hit a wall. What I want to know in general is this. In almost all other programming languages that I've used there is a simple way of drawing arbitrarily on screen. Usually there is some sort of Scene or Canvas type class and another GraphicObject type class. So If, say, I want to draw a car, I create a class that descends from GraphicObject and define they it draws itself and then add an instantiation of the Car class (the object) to the Scene. If I want a second car, you just instantiate another and put it wherever you like, by setting some kind of coordinate function. If this is a program where what is drawn depends on user input, everything must be done programatically and hence it does not depend on anything other than the code written.

How do you achieve this in Android? As far as I can muster the only object which you can define the way it is drawn is a View. However I have not been able to simply take my custom view (that draws a rectangle in my case) and instantiate two of them a put them in the screen where I want them, and do this in a programtic simple way....

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I answer for Canvas in the answers below, not on OpenGL ES....

Comment: I've had a little bit of experience with open GL. What I want to do is not terribly complex as it involves drawing cards and text mostly, I may give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I want to draw lets say 10 rectangles then I wont instantiate my custom `View` 10 times. Instead I will add logic in my custom `View` to be able to draw 10 or more rectangles. Anyway if you want to draw again what was drawn in a `View` then you can call `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` on your `View` and then call `getDrawingCache()` to get `Bitmap` to draw it somewhere else.

Comment: So what your are saying is that I shoud use only one view to draw anything I might need? As for your second proposal. If I don't want to draw again the exact same thing (I want to change the color and size for example), would this method still work?

Comment: `So what your are saying is that I shoud use only one view to draw anything I might need?` no. I am saying if you are may be trying to instantiate the same view as your question suggested here `However I have not been able to simply take my custom view (that draws a rectangle in my case) and instantiate two of them a put them in the screen where I want them` then you can just add the functionality of drawing the same thing twice in that view.

Comment: And if the thing is same e.g. a rectangle but the size and color is being changed then yes you can use just one view that will have `addRect(color, size)` kind of method and view will take care of drawing newly added rectangle as well. Even If you are aiming to write a drawing app that lets user draw some basic shapes then again yes this can and should be done in just one View. IMHO.

Comment: I have thought of this solution before. I definitely can do this. Just one more question, though. I need to have input where I detect which rectangle is pressed. What I should do is (I'm asking here) get the coordinate where the screen was touched and check all my rectangles to see if it fell within their bounds, right? PS: Thank you for your answer!!!!

Comment: exactly... this is the only way and same way is being used in Android's built-in ViewGroup. Take the touch point and check for every rectangle circle etc. and stop as soon as you detect one. Of course you should have a z-order in which you should traverse. Otherwise if views are overlapping then you might not satisfy your users.

Comment: Since I know, how to do this and It seem reasonable, I think I just found the winner!!! Thank you for all your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

Its almost same in android also,

All the widgets are inherited from class View, by extending this class you can actually create whatever you want limiting by only yours imagination, you have access to canvas here, use it along with touch controls exposed from class itself to override all the behaviours you want as per your need,.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: I can draw a view to whatever I like, on that we agree. I draw it by using the onDraw method and a Canvas. Ok. However the problem comes when I want to put several instances of the View at a position that I like on the screen. How do I do this? With canvas the only way I can figure out is to just draw everything I want and have the View occupy the entire screen....

Comment: Read about  FrameLayout than,

Comment: I've been reading and it says that a FrameLayout is done so I can add 1 View, specifically. I want to add multiple views and put them where I want them. None of the answer so far (save for OpenGL ES) have a setPos method or somthing like that....

Comment: well in framelayout you can add multiple view a same point, they are draw in layered faishion.